# 'If' condition in batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, dos

I am having problems getting the desired result in cmd batch file. I need to print the result in the below mentioned format

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%i in (8 7 6 5 4 3 2) do (

echo %%i
if %%i EQU 8 goto lvl8
if %%i EQU 3 goto lvl35
if %%i EQU 2 (goto lvl3) else goto lvls

:lvl8
set str1=8
set str2=16

:lvl35
set str1=3.5
set str2=4

:lvl3
set str1=3
set str2=3.5

:lvls
set str1=%%i

set /A str2=%%i+1

echo %%i
rem echo.!str!
echo.!str1!
echo.!str2!
)
endlocal
```

Expected outputs

```
8
8
16
7
7
8
6
6
7
5
5
6
4
4
5
3
3.5
4
2
3
3.5
```

Right now am getting the following:

```
8
Missing operand
%i

%i
3.5
```

**EDIT:** updated the above question as per Joey's solution.

Comment: **True** MS-DOS batch files were `.bat` files - MS-DOS never had `.cmd`; that would be the Windows (NT) command processor, but that's **NOT** MS-DOS

Comment: marc_s: I resorted to just silently editing by now. Educating people about such things has proven to be futile ...

Comment: marc_s & Joey : sorry if I was a noob in this.

Comment: To debug problems in "BATCH" files, temporarily turn off the top line: REM at-echo off - you will then get a per-line trace of execution rather than just viewing the whole file as a black box. This is the very first -simplest- troubleshooting technique; creating correct "BATCH" scripts without it is somewhere between difficult and impossible. When you've found and fixed the problem, turn the top line back on: at-echo off (for @echo typed at-echo because otherwise stackoverflow chokes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%i%` has no value. Were you intending to use `%%i`?

To clarify, what `cmd` sees here:

```
if  EQU 8 goto lvl8
if  EQU 3 goto lvl35
if  EQU 2 (goto lvl3) else goto lvls
```

which clearly is a syntax error.

---

Ok, after your edit, there are a few problems, still. If you use `goto` you apparently leave the `for` loop. Thus, after a `goto` `%%i` doesn't have a value, either *and* the loop only runs once.

Then there is the way you use the `goto`s; a `goto` is a jump to a specific line in code. Program flow continues normally after that and thus if you jump to `lvl8` you end up running all subsequent lines, too, even those after `:lvl35` and `:lvl3` or `:lvls`. After each section you jump to you'd have to include an explicit jump to the end of the loop to skip the unwanted lines. But that's semi-beside the point, as you cannot use `goto` within the `for` loop, as mentioned above.

So the first thing you should do is get rid of `goto` and instead use structured programming. `if` can accept a block, too. Then you output `%%i` once too often, which can easily be corrected, too.

It now looks like this here:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%i in (8 7 6 5 4 3 2) do (
    echo %%i

    if %%i EQU 8 (
        set str1=8
        set str2=16
    ) else if %%i EQU 3 (
        set str1=3.5
        set str2=4
    ) else if %%i EQU 2 (
        set str1=3
        set str2=3.5
    ) else (
        set str1=%%i
        set /A str2=%%i+1
    )

    rem echo %%i
    rem echo.!str!
    echo.!str1!
    echo.!str2!
)
endlocal
```

Note that each `if` also has an `else` to avoid running the last `else` for all numbers except `2`. The output is now correct. Code can be found [in my SVN repository](http://svn.lando.us/joey/Public/SO/8352303/8352303.cmd), too.

Comment: did as you said..but still the results are erroneous. Please check the updated question above. Appreciate your help.